# In QC, under the Dashboard module can reports be saved in .csv format?

Tags: quality-center, csv-file

In QC - Dashboard module - I have a report which has huge data that exceeds Excel limit. Is there a way to save it in .CSV format?

Answer (score 1):

If allowed and possible, better idea would be to break the report in multiple sub reports. This way you will be able to get all required data.